# iOS -- is there any method call automatically(Inside UIViewController) in same screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any method to call a web service automatically?

Currently i am developing an app like Taxi related app by using Google Maps SDK.

I had 2 applications like **DRIVER & RIDER**. If Driver login in to the application. When ever In User application user should press the request ride then only i want to display Count down timer in Driver app by using web services

The main thing is --> In DRIVER application there was an screen like "Main Screen"(following image). There is no refresh button. How can i get User request in Same screen automatically refresh the UIViewController screen when ever driver get request from server end.

I know some default methods like: ViewDidLoad, ViewWillAppear, ViewWillDisAppear and etc.., --> these all methods call while specific time only like coming from one screen to another (or) while dismiss

In  my case how can i rectify this issue

[image]

Already i used code like:

```
NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 60.0 target: self
                               selector: @selector(callAfterSixtySecond:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
```

After each 60.0 second , iOS will call the below function

```
-(void) callAfterSixtySecond:(NSTimer*) t 
 {
  //Here i call my server API
 }
```

But this is not the feasable solution

Comment: please use 
`dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(60.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self  callAfterSixtySecond];
});`

Comment: Is it feasible  solution to call every 60 sec to my web server API . I hope might be crashes should occur. How can i overcome air this scenario

Comment: then you are using best solution. otherwise try below code if its worked or not tell me after use.....

Comment: `// set clock to current date...
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

NSTimeInterval timeSinceLastSecond = date.timeIntervalSince1970 - floor(date.timeIntervalSince1970);
NSTimeInterval nextMinutes = (60 - dateComponents.second) - timeSinceLastSecond;

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(nextMinutes * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self callAfterSixtySecond];
});
`

Comment: Use WebSocket, something like pusher.com will be your solution

Answer (score 1):

You can send Push notification to from your server, this will could be use to trigger events in your application. You can do it without notification.

Check this for example:

http://hayageek.com/ios-silent-push-notifications/'

That's would be an easy way, now if you want to get complex read up on the [Inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

Comment: Hi @meda. You mentioned like "You can do it without notification". How can i do? can you please explained me

Comment: @MannamBrahmam I meant you could make it silent did you see the [link](http://hayageek.com/ios-silent-push-notifications/)